# Auto selection of text in textfield on tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitextfield

In my application, I have a textbox which is very small. I want to highlight the text in it once user tap in it so then on typing next character, previous text (highlighted on tap) goes away and newly entered data replaces it.

I have tried with following code:

```
UITextField *aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
aTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

But since textfield is very small, this does not suit here. I want to hightlight the text on tap without any control showing up and then on tap of next character I will replace the highlighted text. Any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `UIResponderStandardEditActions` category on `UITextField`. This is not a surprising thing to overlook; it's somewhat buried in the docs.

```
[self.textField selectAll:nil];
```

Comment: How to set background color of selected text?